# How to capture traffic with Fiddler and record it with Jmeter from android device without wi-fi

Tags: android, jmeter, usb, fiddler, traffic

I need to capture traffic from the android device, but i can't use the standard way  with proxy settings during wi-fi connection. Cause i connected to the  network by usb using gnirehtet. Network works clearly, but Fiddler can't see the traffic. If there any oportunity to catch it with Fiddler and to record in Jmeter? Probably somebody faced with it. 
Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

1. You can consider using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) instead of Fiddler, it is more advanced sniffer tool which is capable of listening on multiple interfaces, decrypt SSL traffic, supports way more protocols, etc.
2. If you have a rooted Android device you can run [tcpdump](https://www.androidtcpdump.com/) tool directly on it. Once done you will be able to import generated .pcap file into Fiddler (or aforementioned Wireshark)
3. And finally you can go for "normal" way of recording the traffic using JMeter, but you will need to set **the machine where gnirehtet is running** (not the Android device) to use JMeter as a proxy. Check out [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) for configuration instructions.

Comment: ps. Fiddler Anywhere is back to Linux again!